# How to Find Free Space in Oracle table

Tags: database, oracle

In the below script i am checking regularly the table size in my oracle database but i would like to be able to check free space on the database too.

Is there any way to add how much the free space is ? please

```
select  user_segments.SEGMENT_NAME                                      AS Table_Name,
    user_segments.BYTES/1024/1024                                   AS Table_Size_MB,
    my_indexes.Indexes_Size_MB                                      AS Indexes_Size_MB,
    ((user_segments.BYTES/1024/1024) + my_indexes.Indexes_Size_MB)  AS Tot_Size_MB,
    u_tables.Num_Rows                                               AS NUM_ROWS

from USER_SEGMENTS

inner join (
            select 
                 TABLE_NAME             AS INDX_TABLE_NAME, 
                 SUM(BYTES)/1024/1024   AS Indexes_Size_MB 
                             
            from (
                     select 
                         user_indexes.TABLE_NAME, 
                         user_segments.SEGMENT_NAME, 
                         user_segments.BYTES 
                   
                     from user_segments
                         inner join user_indexes ON user_segments.SEGMENT_NAME = user_indexes.INDEX_NAME
                 ) group by TABLE_NAME
         ) my_indexes on my_indexes.INDX_TABLE_NAME = user_segments.SEGMENT_NAME
         
inner join (
            select 
                TABLE_NAME AS USR_TABLE_NAME, 
                Num_Rows 
            from user_tables
            ) u_tables on u_tables.USR_TABLE_NAME = my_indexes.INDX_TABLE_NAME
            

            
order by TOT_SIZE_MB desc;
```

Comment: I suspect you want to query `dba_free_space` but it isn't obvious to me how you would want to incorporate that into this query which is returning results at a segment level rather than at a tablespace level.  If you want free space at a segment level, you could run `dbms_space.space_usage` for each segment (assuming you're using automatic segment space management).

Comment: no sorry, i mean the free space in each tables

Comment: OK.  So you don't want "free space on the database", you want the free space within the segment.  If so, assuming ASSM, you'd need to call `dbms_space.space_usage` for each segment.  That will give you the number of unformatted blocks, the number of blocks that are 0-25%, 25-50%, 50-75%, and 75-100% free space.  You'd need to decide how you want to present that information (i.e. combine those values to give a single number, add several columns to the result, etc.).

Comment: This sounds like a classic 'x-y question'.  What problem will you solve by knowing the amount of 'free space'?  How do you define "free space"?

Comment: @JustinCave yes, not  "free space on the database" but free space in each table. im beginner in oracle i dont know if i can include  `dbms_space.space_usage` into my script. For more details im droping some rows in my tables then i want to check the free space after this cleanup.i appreciate if you can help me more.

Comment: You probably can't easily drop `dbms_space.space_usage` into a query, no.  I suppose you could write a pipeline table function that calls `dbms_space.space_usage` and then returns the data in a form that you could then join into this query (again, depending on exactly what you would want to be reported).  But if you are just deleting some data from a table and you don't expect that table to grow again, you could just call `dbms_space.space_usage` for that particular table or shrink the table in question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what you could do

Here's my table starting "clean"

```
SQL> create table t as
  2  select d.* from dba_objects d,
  3   ( select 1 from dual connect by level <= 20 );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> select num_rows, avg_row_len,  blocks, empty_blocks
  2  from user_tables
  3  where table_name = 'T';

  NUM_ROWS AVG_ROW_LEN     BLOCKS EMPTY_BLOCKS
---------- ----------- ---------- ------------
   1745660         131      33746            0

1 row selected.
```

Now I'll try see if I can get to the number using an estimate based on the stats I have

```
SQL> select num_rows*avg_row_len/8192*100/(100-pct_free) est_blocks
  2  from user_tables
  3  where table_name = 'T';

EST_BLOCKS
----------
31016.9081

1 row selected.
```

I'm close but a little bit off which is to be expected, because blocks have some overhead etc. But I can find out what the overhead is

```
SQL> select round(32300/29800,2) est_overhead from dual;

EST_OVERHEAD
------------
        1.08

1 row selected.
```

So if I factor in that 8% into my calcs (for a clean table), I can now use the dictionary stats to get a good estimate of the expected blocks required for this table given the nunber of rows and their size is.

```
SQL> select num_rows*avg_row_len/8192*100/(100-pct_free)*1.08 est_blocks
  2  from user_tables
  3  where table_name = 'T';

EST_BLOCKS
----------
33498.2607

1 row selected.
```

Armed with this information, you can now do easy comparisons between what the size of a table is, versus what you would *expect* it to be based on the rows it contains

```
SQL> delete from t
  2  where mod(object_id,3) = 0;

582000 rows deleted.

SQL>
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('','T')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

My calc suggests the table should be 22329 blocks but its actually 33746.

```
SQL> select blocks, num_rows*avg_row_len/8192*100/(100-pct_free)*1.08 est_blocks
  2  from user_tables
  3  where table_name = 'T';

    BLOCKS EST_BLOCKS
---------- ----------
     33746  22329.999

1 row selected.
```

Lets see how good the estimate was. I'll reorg the table to reclaim that space

```
SQL> alter table t move;

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('','T')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> select num_rows, avg_row_len,  blocks, empty_blocks
  2  from user_tables
  3  where table_name = 'T';

  NUM_ROWS AVG_ROW_LEN     BLOCKS EMPTY_BLOCKS
---------- ----------- ---------- ------------
   1163660         131      22536            0

1 row selected.

SQL>
```

So you can use a similar approach (and 8% is probably a good enough fudge factor)

Comment: thanks for your help @connor it's more clear for me now :)